# Cannot display aggregate sum value in html using django framework

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I have been trying to sum a column of values from my django database and and render it in the html where required. The views component is as follows:

```
    def get(self, request):
        payments = Payment.objects.all()
        payments.sumOfPayments = payments.aggregate(Sum('instalment_amount'))
        return render(
            request,
            'monthly_budget/monthly_budget_list.html',
            {'payments': payments})
```

and the html portion is like this:

`<h1>{{payments.sumOfPayments}}</h1>`

I seem to be going around in circles at the moment. Could anyone shed any light as to where I am going wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@benm4ckenzie The code below is to take sum of all the columns.

```
payments.sumOfPayments = payments.aggregate(Sum('instalment_amount'))
```

But the sum should not be saved back to

```
payments.sumOfPayments
```

Because payments is a queryset, which doesn't have a property called sumOfPyaments.

Right way to do it will be:

```
sumOfPayments = payments.aggregate(Sum('instalment_amount'))
```

Here is the whole code corrected:

```
def get(self, request):
    payments = Payment.objects.all()
    sumOfPayments = payments.aggregate(Sum('instalment_amount'))
    return render(
        request,
        'monthly_budget/monthly_budget_list.html',
        {'payments': payments, 'sumOfPayments': sumOfPayments})
```

Here is a html for this.

```
<h1>{{ sumOfPayments }}</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you. Managed to get the value rendered and placed the variable inside a context dictionary